# javascript - many scripts on page should run one by one

Tags: javascript

is there any native javascript function to run script one by one (no jquery).
I describe what I mean.

**My html file is:**

```
<html><body>
  Hello
  <script type="text/javascript" src="sleep.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  alert('boo');
  </script>
</body></html>
```

**sleep.js:**

```
setTimeout(myFunction, 3000);
function myFunction(){
    alert('hi');
}
```

When I load my page alert 'boo' shows immediatelly and after 3 seconds it shows alert 'hi'. But I want to execute scripts one by one (as they follow in html file), so first script sleep.js should be executed as first one, it sleeps for 3 seconds, then shows 'hi', and then second alert shows 'boo'.

**How this can be done?**

P.S.This is just a short example, I need if for any scripts, for example if first script will be google analytics code, it should be executed first, then if first script finished run second script, then third script, one by one.

Comment: Check the dupe. If you don't feel that's answered there, then ask me here. I will be happy to open this up for you. :)

Comment: To say in short, `setTimeout()` is asynchronous. So, you need a callback to execute correctly.

Comment: Thanks for clarification! One more question - is there any option how to globally setup in part where "alert hi" is located that it should wait until all other scripts finish and then execute alert hi and everything behind it? (if not, I will delete this question) Thank you again.

Comment: I guess you are asking for a function similar to `$.ajaxComplete` right? I don't think it is there. I might be wrong. You don't need to delete this question. :)

Comment: yes, it is very similar (but I don't want to use jquery) - but it should work very similar to that function it term of meaning, that last function should be executed after all other function finished.

Comment: Yeah I am not saying about jQuery at all. Just comparing your request, but yea, there's no such function exists till now.

Comment: Praveen, thank you for your help! :)

Comment: Does it solve anything? Sorry I am unable to answer. :(

Comment: Well, it didn't solve my problem, but you said there is no function exists till now, so I can stop searching solution for this. (I understood it can't be done now)

Comment: Ah... Something to make you happy!